# Merge multiple Map and differentiate their value with different keys in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap

EDIT: I have three maps with following format:

```
 map1.put("aaa",1);
 map1.put("bbb",1);
 map1.put("ccc",1);

 map2.put("aaa",2);
 map2.put("bbb",3);

 map3.put("ccc",6);
 map3.put("ddd",6);
```

Now I want the result as list with following format:

```
[{"id":"aaa","map1count":"1","map2count":"2","map3count":"0"},
 {"id":"bbb","map1count":"1","map2count":"0","map3count":"0"},
 {"id":"ccc","map1count":"1","map2count":"0","map3count":"6"},
 {"id":"ddd","map1count":"0","map2count":"0","map3count":"6"}]
```

How can I do this in java, help me to figure out.

Comment: You do it by writing some code to gather the result, then use a JSON library to format it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for (homework) help must include a summary of the **work done so far** to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class Count, with three members ex. mapCount1, mapCount2, mapCount3. Now create result map

```
HashMap<String, Count>() result = new HashMap<>();
```

Now you need to traverse these 3 maps, check map.containsKey(key), here  key might be "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" etc. Now traverse first map, since map doesnt not contain any key, add key with value to result map. Now do this for 2nd, 3rd map, If key is there and then get value of count object and update count for mapCount2/3. At last for each key you can print count specific to each map.